# Spring MVC ResquestMapping 'POST' not supported

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller

[image]I have a method with get and post in login controller. When application is deployed from index page i am redirecting to login page it makes GET request(/login.htm) it works fine but when i make post request with JSON body it says Request method 'POST' not supported i am using postman tool to test please

Help

```
@RequestMapping(value="/login",method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView redirectLoginForm()
{
    System.out.println("Login Page...");
    return new ModelAndView("login");
}

@RequestMapping(value="/login",method=RequestMethod.POST,
                                consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
                                produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<Login> login(@RequestBody Login login)
{
            System.out.println("Checking LoginCredentials...");

            boolean isValid=loginServiceBo.checkUserLogin(login);

            if(isValid)
            {
                return new ResponseEntity<Login>(login, HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
            }

            return new ResponseEntity<>(login, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);   
}
```

Comment: can you share screenshot of postman where you are triggering a request.

Comment: Do you have csrf enabled somewhere in your app ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking in account your code:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/login",method=RequestMethod.POST,
                            consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
                            produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
```

In the screenshot of Postman, is missing the correct mapping, it should be: http://localhost:8073/Spring_Hibernate_Project/login

Answer (score 0):

I think it's connected with your postman query.

May be my screenshot will be helpful to check your postman, on server side I have very similar mapping.

[image]